# GET request to download PDF using apisauce in react native

Tags: react-native, apisauce

I am using apisauce for basic HTTP requests like GET and POST, and it works well. Now I need to be able to download pdf files too. Is this possible with apisauce? If so does anyone have some sample code?

Because when I tried to hit the API in postman, I got a response like this below. after I save the response as a file, and the pdf looks good. but when I hit the API using apisauce in react native, I got null in data. even I added responsetype: 'blob' when creating the API, but it doesn't work. do i need to add anything when create the API.

```
��WkL��wfv�\`Yc؅]��������cwyc�`��/����G�*7�U;)q+��4��4�\+�I�ZV�����?v��m*9�e{��{g�-��g4s�=�s���9wgFE��"h2Yw��p~O�����wd]��6u�w��O�����9�����0_��npdznf5:��0��֜��o�bb����q�A>�W�\3�=����}E��0�!�i�VԊ#�DVlnt�r,�p]������Jw,kVW���b���_"2�-��
"�!���R�zR %JEȦ�*�Z�ώ�H��\Z�
'��cOs�C%8h�j��Z.\,m~}�<��2��ߞ]�xq�9~~~�|��~<����W6إT�BiZ�V�U���c\��S�X�|kU�cX-z�Wp!��M§�M�
    s�"S��D
�����"�5�H(a�e.A�qW�,���W�sga�!���I�rU�+��t�!g��<�4�&�m�����g>�>y��!�~?�~����C6�'������+܃��b���q9mVU�29B�m~�c��_��j�3��r:]
A�4��׸BYU�����])�'9�xKC��L�hW�ly�\�r�ٍ܌c�ɥ�7��ۚ;M��ƪ�t��7mf��OQ�쬲��֡����n�;�7�p|���9��7�WWge��w�Vc���<�qv��UJbBBBbM�V[PPRR���9����Ɩ�l��8SS�IV%$��'y����4��eeA|���i��""Cn�        U�$Kt\�,���v@J �o���k�i��l�s��ǆ���(*i �����G������UOL�
�Z��꓋�v��۝fffd����O&'1�ޔ|�f�D��-C���PI(��M�&�kq�Ba�����^�_��|�Se��e�#�,���^}a_)����}/�\8Ii����wvC_�/�L�S���;��*�m��`�d#   %E��l�9�m޵�)6��pz)2*.�|H�l���>|��$�{baV�G��g�b62�"jպ�{r+�p�e����v
��$�0���ҝ��1qJU�6�Z���&&�������Y�;�'���8�����e�]��B����Fƥ���Q1�1[RRY-.����Z�J��o�x=���_V�i�e����p�~���J�1 2ם�)G�D���ZP<
n�]�.�����l7�L�ֹ�gw�T{��t��VOuK�����ƃO��WO,46�n`U���԰���lV*��=u���ԭJ�\Z�hn�Xl����Ʌ�={*_�y+�m�/T��l{����z�����|`���X�:��܇�A��5�f�%r-�����.f]�Z%,$ǘsG�&������#O��5
�1�/4��=u�!h8z4������ӯ,jo5�����qzq���l���K&�1��piv����B�gs`r�c����b���0��K�;wH��Q�K���0%'����Í��pf��::<��<��r=������v���<����]D�yW'�f�dT�t�����C����,8������z�ݕ:�
��e?\ˇ��Ļ x� {NӃ��P��<9u]�9�������(J��eo-��kh)r9cq�w�Hg���x�!?/��r��j��S������Oe�.}��E�q��ϡ��T&��)}\��s�g�j�U��u�]�L���$�zB���%��a���)Q�˞�"�W��#���e7���k��G��������%Zst�S�w`��T����\�:ɨ0�X���hk�nl�����b��k蓼3����V���_-Lr��-�%������$�N�/I����4k���ؤDE�!W/�cӱ��DedB�"������v��-La9}M�qz�V'�����[������;B���dV���Հ�Z���D8�
�ԡ���Qe�૵��̲����Z�n4��:�G
�fc�Q�'�{���T슉_ۀ�/�V�?V��+�j^�����wm/l����do-���UV���Җ=���(E�Z`��vfs6������7�,[R�4%��r�[g��l�p7B��Bg�5�9��8��=��H�Z��
���i��{b���"c�b�&07���������)7�S�1��Q�b�:�[���WSﯭ��"]_��W�F��U>oC��W%쥟���Y6�����~�&�]���X�|�
�BHqrնj�w��JW�l�榐MևV���OB�4����8�ͨ���V���]E+� �z�'���̓��p�GA΅Z�|��E����2k��AЄ/W�D3p����|<���W���e�0��4��b�ȥq�pK���uY�{�_7��\��e�U����xD�I�D3� �,*�r��|�H�M�A��#��DG�����Hdgޗ�(��ܐ�hdec$:�հ;$:�坨��q4�&�@�h�/X�01��5ں��U��@����S�׏F`$�rFQ/H'�.ywSYHr��i���9lB��m�akF�92�qx5
Z��)x&Ѭd�
V�R�`a���Io� ��`�_�{���n�!^�7����5+�4�ۂ�Bl���Q7�)��i�w���u���)��x��g� �9��
�Ad�t�,�,Tf�oA'HG`���Y���`���;�qB-�a��!���w�3M3�G��
�c���6�C4j�K����5YP�Jq�Q������8H��P�34�Z�j�Cyj��@����JVxuN�N��i��jl�8M�.�mU�%��(�c��T�-�Lx]c����r�=H�_U�N,4�u���w=ǳ���b���n����JO"��Й�$��#y������@��>O�7F}t����+D��T��r�/>�N:����Di�2�k��r8;�퇹N�&�n#�+`�C
���Т��V�턱$d
��/�#f��A�������4������7��P�Fc�T���U{�J
��( >�T
```

I have searched in google but I don't have any clue and i am new to react native.

Can anyone please let me know how to solve this issue.

Comment: Your question is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67439415/download-the-pdf-file-using-apisauce-in-react-native/67440280#67440280

Comment: Use package **rn-fetch-blob** and can you show us URL of pdf and code snippet?